# Face cropping using facial landmarks

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, face-recognition

I have facial landmark coordinates and I want to crop the frontal face as precisely as possible without loosing facial information as shown in figure:

[image]

I have already tried drawing circles from nose center, but it is not very precise. if somebody has done this before can help me with the idea of doing so in a good way with the pseudo-code. I will code it later.

Comment: You probably need more land marks if you are going to do it accurately.  Ear location, top of head and chin I would think is all you would need.

Comment: if you have found the correct answer please post it here

Answer (score 0):

This data is not enough for face cropping. Use `dlib` or `opencv` libraries. They have methods to get 68 landmarks.